# Selenium opens browser but returns with an error

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, python-3.5, ubuntu-17.04

On running this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/google-chrome")
```

exits with this error after opening a browser with a new tab

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
self.assert_process_still_running()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
% (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/google-chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0
```

and after that I am unable to use the driver variable as it returns a NameError.

I installed selenium with pip and I am using python 3.5.3.

## Edit 1:

I forgot to mention that i am using Ubuntu 17.04 zesty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are using **`Selenium 3.x.x`** along with the recent **`Google Chrome`** browsers, you have to download **`chromedriver.exe`** from [this location](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) place it in your system and mention the absolute location of the **`chromedriver`** binary through the argument **`executable_path`** as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Please include the same steps for linux also and I will then accept your answer. (my problem arose due to a version conflict which was resolved when I checked the chromedriver)

Comment: Check out my updated Answer and let me know the status.